# jquery checkbox and array help

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi There I need to get the names and values of checkboxes that have been checked into an array name selected, I cannot for life of me get it working, below is my attempt, if someone could clrify what I am doing wrong that would be brilliant.

```
//Location AJAX
    //var dataObject = new Object();
    var selected = new Array();
    $('#areas input.radio').change(function(){ // will trigger when the checked status changes
        var checked = $(this).attr("checked"); // will return "checked" or false I think.
        // Do whatever request you like with the checked status
        if(checked == true) {
        /*$("input:checked").each(function() {
                selected.push($(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val();
            });
                alert(selected)*/
                getQuery = $(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val()+"&location_submit=Next";
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"/search/location",
                    data: getQuery,
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(getQuery);
                        console.log(data);
                        //  $('body.secEmp').html(data);
                    }
                });
        } else {
            //do something to remove the content here
            alert("Remove");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you use Firbug? If so, do get any error messages? If you do not use it, use it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the closing parantheses on the call to `selected.push`. It should be:

```
selected.push($(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val());
```

Otherwise, it looks fine.

Another, possibly simpler, way to do the same thing is to use `map` instead of `each`:

```
var selected = $('input:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val();
}).get();
```

Comment: I noticed that right at the moment of posting, I notice this gives a comma seperated array, I am sending this array as a query string is there a way for me replace the comma with a  &

Comment: @sea_1987: Use `selected.join('&')`

Comment: @interjay: selected.join('&') shows no change, it is still comma seperated

Comment: `join` works for me. Note that it won't change the value of `selected`: you need to use the value that `selected.join('&')` returns.

Comment: how should I be using, I dont really follow, I doing that method and then alerting selected and still seeing commas.